# how can I delet "None" in code output

Tags: python, python-2.7

how can I delet "None" in code output .I don't want to appear 'None' in code output

```
>>class class1:
     name='civil'
     def printname(self,name):
         print self.name
         print name
>>you=class1()
>>you.mark=100
>>print you.printname('shahram'),you.mark

  civil
  shahram
  None 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you.printname('shahram')
```

already prints the name

print this separately

```
you.printname('shahram')
print(you.mark)
```